# Write from a c-file to a h-file and then to another h-file in C

Tags: c, header-files

I have a header file where I can activate logging with the following #define DEF_LOGGING_PRINT, if I comment //#define DEF_LOGGING_PRINT then logging is deactivated. I have added the following in the header-file:

```
#define activated 1

#define deactivated 2
 
#define act_or_dea_log_(x)

#if x == activated

#define DEF_LOGGING_PRINT

#elif x == deactivated

#define DEF_LOGGING_PRINT
#endif
```

Is it possible to write to this x from another header file, somethine like this:

```
#define act_or_dea_log(x) act_or_dea_log_(x)
```

And then at last from a c-file do ”act_or_dea_log("activated");” to choose to
activate logging, i.e. the alternative #if x == activated?

Have tried many options, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You can't have preprocessor directives within a macro - as this seem to be the thing you are trying to do with your `act_or_dea_log_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if i interpreted what you writed properly, no because they are preprocessor's meaning everything is done before any code runs meaning when it is compiled
I recommend you using the starting arguments of the program
Gengetopt is a great way to easily implement

https://www.gnu.org/software/gengetopt/gengetopt.html